# Complex number exponential form negative i

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

What does negative i mean in exponential form of a complex number?

[image]

Is it equal to $5e^{i6\pi/5}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exponential complex representation just implies that that complex number you have has a circular-like figure in the complex plane.
If you simply wanna solve it, then you take -24π/5 to 6π/5 due to the repetition of the waves and get the result.

An interesting way to look at this, and this is just as I see it, would be that as e^{ix} give the curve with vector pointing outwards of the origin so it's conjugate must have the vector pointing toward the origin. But that just increases complexity in complex. So you better not dive into it.

Hope this helps!!